# node.js socket.io middleware

Tags: node.js, socket.io

In node.js we can add some middleware function to socket.io server like this

```
 io.use(function(socket, next) {
            var req = socket.handshake;
            var res = {};
            cookieParser(req, res, function(err) {
                if (err) return next(err);
                session(req, res, next);
            });
        });
```

I wonder if we can add some kind of middleware to simple socket.on function as in the following example

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('someSignal',
             function(data,next){/*middleware function code*/ next();},
             function(data){})
});
```

Comment: You are aware, that every request is going through a piece of middleware? So your first example already solves your problem.

Comment: @Marco, I need to perform some special actions for specific group of socket signals, but not for all. First example executes middleware func for all sockets are connected

Comment: There is no message-specific middleware in socket.io.  So, why not just make a shared function that each event handler that wants to use the particular middleware function can call as its first line?  It's "manual" middleware, but it's really simple to implement.

Answer (score 1):

emitter.on(event, listener) is the alias for emitter.addListener(event, listener).
if you want to do this, every request pass through this middleware will add one eventListener.

Comment: I have to call one lister after another or even stop it's executing at all. Is this possible using this approach?

Comment: you should not call listener manually, node.js event loop will do this for you.

Comment: however if you want to emit event to specific client you can use : io.clients[sessionID].send(), not sure is that helpful to you.

Comment: @胡學賓I want to block event loop to exucute on or more eventListener relying what previos event listener result is. (I need to create waterfall model for those listeners)

Comment: why not just put this logic in a single listener? I mean in the listener you can feel free to execute on or more logic which is wrap in a function.

Comment: Check this out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/composable-middleware
Maybe this one is useful to you.